# Compiling C++ packages with standard library using Conda

Tags: c++, compilation, conda

I'm trying to build a [conda](https://conda.io/docs/) package that compiles some C++ code and installs it. When I compile the code on my base system (i.e. not using `conda build`) it works just fine, when I compile it using `conda build .` I get the following error in a couple of different places

```
gexiv2/gexiv2-metadata-gps.cpp:29:20: error: no member named 'overflow_error' in namespace 'std'
    throw std::overflow_error("Invalid fraction");
          ~~~~~^
```

Taking a peak in my build environment, I see that the build environment is lacking the `stdexcept` header that would otherwise be present in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/stdexcept` (at least on MacOS Sierra).

Is there a way to make `conda` install the headers for the C++ standard library as a dependency for the build process? I've looked through the list of packages and I don't see one that installs these common headers.

Comment: The constructor taking `const char*` has only been available since C++11, check the compilation flags. see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/overflow_error  Might not be this as I would expect a different error message.

Comment: First, a minor detail: On my Sierra system, the headers are in `/usr/include`, not `/usr/local/include`.  Anyway, if the compiler is able to use those system headers outside of the conda build environment, I would expect them to be available in the build environment, too.  Does your build script rely on environment variables such as `CXXFLAGS`? If so, you may need to define them in your `build.sh` script.  (Environment variables from your shell are not inherited by the build process.)